# Better edit box for moderators editing flagged comments

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, moderation

Currently, the interface for moderators to edit a flagged comments uses an `input` instead of a `textarea`. For comments longer than a few words, this is cumbersome. It's not possible to read the entire comment at once.

Can we get a `textarea` instead of an `input` when editing flagged comments?

**Note:** Editing a comment on a question by clicking the "edit" link works just fine; it's just flagged comments interface ("delete | edit | dismiss") where the input field is obnoxious.

Comment: Is it an `input` or `textarea`?

Comment: I flagged a comment for you to check.